# Photoshop Masking vs. Illustration Masking. Why are layers in the opposite order?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, sketch-app, adobe-after-effects, clipping-mask

[image]

To mask an image, why in Photoshop (or Sketch) is the mask under the image, while in Illustrator (or After Effects) the mask is above the image?

Answer (score 1):

Because the masks do different things.

The clipping mask you show in Photoshop does a slightly different thing. Conceptually you could see it as painting the top image on any opaque pixels in the bottom image so the order makes sense like that. The clipping mask in Illustrator just uses a path to reveal parts of the containing image.

The equivalent in Photoshop of the clipping mask in Illustrator is a layer or vector mask, which looks like this:

[image: Photoshop layer masks]

The real answer though is simply: that's how the UI was designed. I'm sure many programs display masks differently.